# SQL Query On Date When Type Is VARCHAR

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to query a database with a between 2 dates... The problem is the column that I am querying contains dates that are currently formatted like this "01/01/2014" (dd/mm/yyyy) with a column type of VARCHAR.

At the moment, I can't convert the column to a date type.

Basically when I query the table because it's not set to date type the between query doesn't return the correct rows...

Has anyone else come across this problem, is there something I can change within the query?

```
$this->db->where('IssueDate >=', '02/12/2013');
$this->db->where('IssueDate <=', '22/01/2014');
$query = $this->db->get('MYTABLE');
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Cast the values to dates in your query.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to use `str_to_date()`:

```
$this->db->where("str_to_date(IssueDate, '%d/%m/%Y') >=", "'2013-12-92'");
$this->db->where("str_to_date(IssueDate, '%d/%m/%Y') <=", "'2014-01-22'");
$
```

You may not have any control over the database.  But you do have control over your own constants.  You should get used to the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD for such constants -- unambiguous and accepted correctly by most databases.

Comment: Gordan, thanks for this... I've tried it and for some reason I'm not getting anything...

This is what I have:

$this->db->where('str_to_date(IssueDate, '%d/%m/%Y') >=', '02/12/2013');

Comment: @WebDevB . . . I don't know if your database will interpret your string as a valid date.  Just use `'2013-12-02'`.

Comment: @WebDevB User double-quotes for `where("")` method, and single-quotes for the SQL query (inside the `str_to_date()` function).

Comment: Like this @HashemQolami $this->db->where("str_to_date(IssueDate, '%d/%m/%Y') >=', '2013-12-02'");

Comment: @WebDevB . . . Have you looked at the revised code?  Use double quotes for strings at the application layer.

Comment: Yea using this: $this->db->where("str_to_date(IssueDate, '%d/%m/%Y') >=', '2013-12-02'");

Comment: @WebDevB . . . You are missing two double quotes, the closing one for the first argument and the opening one for the second.

Comment: sorry this $this->db->where("str_to_date(IssueDate, '%d/%m/%Y') >=", "'2013-12-01'");

In my table the data is set like this "01/01/14"

Comment: Just noticed the data is "01/01/14" so i've changed my query to           $this->db->where("str_to_date(IssueDate, '%d/%m/%y') >=", "'01/12/13'"); but still nothing is being returned...

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest creating a view on the table in the database that transforms the string date columns you have into the following format...   YYYYMMDD

That format is sortable and can easily be compared versus other similar formatted dates - you can even do date arithmetic with it.

Keep in mind that a view does not copy the table or add any performance overhead.  It is often a good idea to access any table through a view even if initially you do not need to perform any manipulations on the underlying table - it will help if you later find you do need to perform them.

Answer (score 0):

use **BETWEEN** clause with **STR_TO_DATE()**. Check below code:-

```
$wh = STR_TO_DATE(`IssueDate`,'%d/%m/%Y')." between '02/12/2013' and '22/01/2014'";
$this->db->where($wh);
```

Expect it'll give You perfect result.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work neither... What am I missing??

Comment: @WebDevB are You getting any error? can You provide You table schema with record? then I can provide You exact solution.