# Converting A SQL Column From VARCHAR to Date

Tags: mysql

After my last post: [SQL Query On Date When Type Is VARCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295533/sql-query-on-date-when-type-is-varchar)

I've decided I'm going to convert the column from a `VARCHAR` to a `DATE` type.

All the fields already have the data setout like "22/01/14".

Has anyone done this before.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: One way to do this would be to create a new column of the correct datatype and convert the data, then remove the old column.

Comment: Yea that's what I was thinking of doing... Create a new field called 'CopyField1' then convert the data to a correct 'data' type...

Delete the old field then rename 'CopyField1' back to the correct name... :-)

Comment: Make sure the the old column doesn't have any foreign key relationships

Answer (score 1):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) like:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('22/01/14','%d/%m/%Y');
+------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('22/01/14','%d/%m/%Y') |
+------------------------------------+
| 2014-01-22                         |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

-so apply it in your `UPDATE` statement. If you're going to change column type, then it will not be safe to change that directly. Let's say your current column has name `str_date`. Then:

- Add new column, like: `ALTER TABLE t ADD new_date DATE`
- Copy proper values: `UPDATE t SET new_date=STR_TO_DATE(str_date,'%d/%m/%Y')`
- Drop old column: `ALTER TABLE t DROP str_date`
- Rename new column: `ALTER TABLE t CHANGE new_date str_date DATE`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change table structure in several sql like this:

```
alter table `mytable` add `_IssueDate` DATE NOT NULL after `IssueDate`;
update `mytable` set `_IssueDate`=STR_TO_DATE(`IssueDate`, '%d/%m/%Y');
alter table `mytable` drop `IssueDate`;
alter table `mytable` change `_IssueDate` `IssueDate` DATE NOT NULL;
```